# Understanding tree rings and estimating the age of this tree

Tags: trees

Our neighborhood is filled with oaks, and I have at least 6 or 7 on my relatively small property (~0.3 acres).  I've always wondered how old they are, and if they pre-date the house or not (this house is just under 20 years old).

My neighbor recently cut down one of her oak trees due to disease (I don't know the details).  It was similar in size to mine - some of mine are smaller and some of mine are bigger, so I figure its age is a rough average for the age of my trees.  I checked the recently cut cross-section near the base of the tree, and while I can clearly see some rings on the inside, they are only distinct for about the inner third of the tree.  I've successfully "aged" other trees like this, so I'm not sure what is going on here (the lack of discernible rings doesn't seem like it is caused by the chainsaw).  In case it helps I'm in North/Central Florida.

Upon further inspection: [The original and very indistinct photo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ozeCFRC5w3gV9OayR2fIj-lkQoON0CyK) of the tree was from when it was freshly cut down a week ago.  [I just took another picture today](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1O0yd1x9kW6KG1mMUjsH69bJWHk8rin3K) and the outer rings stand out substantially more, although now I'm more confused.  Some sections in the middle are still very indistinct, but the outer rings appear **substantially** larger than the inner rings.  Is this normal?  I could understand differences in age/climate making tree growth more favorable, but it appears to be a factor of 2 or 3 difference, which makes me wonder if these outer rings are something other than annual growth rings.  Presuming that the large outer rings are normal annual growth rings, then I think I can find at least 30 distinct rings.  There are areas where there are obviously rings but I can't see them, so I'm guessing it is about 40 years old.

Any guesses as to how old this tree is?  Am I "interpreting" it properly? 
 I've also embedded the pictures below, but doing so required shrinking them.  The above links will take you to the original, higher resolution images.

[image]

Comment: The year rings are not good visible in this picture probably due to light. The white stuff in the middle is probably the disease (looks as fungus). The trunk does however have rings, you can see them a little bit at around 10 O'clock. Also the brown parts in the middle show some ring structure.

Comment: @benn I'm not sure if lighting is the problem.  I couldn't see them any better in person.  I was in shade, but this was in midafternoon on a sunny day.  The light doesn't really get any better.

Comment: I think you should lime away some dirt. Glossy surfaces are easier to read. Do you know the species? To me this tree does no seem old. Maybe 20 years? In your climate maybe also less.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi lime away some dirt?  I still have the stump (the neighbor obviously didn't want it and I figured I'd find a use for it) so if there is something I can do to figure this out I'm up for it (preferably involving common household materials).  Indeed, that's why I asked if it is possible to determine the age of the tree - techniques to help are welcome as an answer, even if you can't tell the age of the tree from the photo.

Comment: You count the circles in the three. Usually one per year + some estimate on how many years it took to get wood on such height (so plus 1 to 3 years). A lime/sandpaper (or some gardening gloves) could help to see better the circles. Normally they are visible. Heavily changing setting on photo handling software could make them more visible. But the true core is in (or very near) the "uncutted" part. Note: now that I look better, the circles seems neared as I was expecting, so maybe it is 30-40 year old

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Looking at it closely now I can count about 17 distinct rings in the inner section of the tree.  The only "rings" I see on the outer side are substantially larger, which makes me suspect that they are not annual growth rings but something else.  I'll see if I can clean it up a bit later and post another picture

Comment: Outer there are around 10 rings (see on bottom, and on right side). When plant is large, it can growth more (and BTW more sun, more leaves, more branches, so also more need to have more vases to/from roots)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi by "lime" do you mean rasp, file, plane or sand away some surface wood to make it smooth and easier to evaluate? Lime in a garden context usually means a white calcium compound. If the latter, what function does the lime powder provide? Thanks.

Comment: @ColinBeckingham: right, as tool, not as geology term.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I just took a recent picture, and a week in the elements has made quite a difference to the appearance.  I also brushed it off, although I did not have a chance to try sanding it yet.

Comment: A belt sander would be best if you can get one. i have counted 80 rings on southern pie ( US ) , but the guy using the chainsaw was good. - easy to see rings.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could go about attempting to verify your age is by estimating the tree's age based on its growth factor. Just figure out the diameter of the tree and then multiply by its growth factor. The growth factor for the Oak is 3. This will give you an approximation for the age of tree which you could use to compare with your other approximation, GL!

Comment: I've never heard of that method before - thanks!

Comment: @conman NP, have fun!

Comment: Can you add a reference to the growth factor that you quote? Thanks!

Comment: @kevinsky Ugh, always making things complicated. It's going to require more than that because it depends on the variety of the oak but of course you knew that didn't you?

Comment: :) From my perspective, I realized very quickly that it depends on the species of oak.  I definitely don't know what species of oak this is, but this answer is still helpful.  Perhaps some simple changes to help future readers by discussing the nature of growth factors, dependence on species, etc?

Comment: @Rob  I was hoping you could refer to a web link, preferably from a university, arborist which showed the growth factors, thanks!

Comment: @Rob: it is not a useful method, if you do no specify the units. Diameter in cm or in inches? The growth factor depends a lot also on the climate (warm, mountain, etc.), and species (and local conditions). BTW there are deciduous oaks, and evergreen oaks. In my experience, such formula is used on forestry management, just for very rough estimates (real age +- 50% of the estimate).